# How do I  migrate facebook comments from my old site A to site B?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have an iFrame Facebook Tab application that uses the `fb:comments` module. I am migrating to a new domain name.

How do I get my old comments on where the new domain will be?

So I want to move my comments from `domainA.com` to `domainB.com`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to migrate comments from one domain to another.  If you wanted, your new domainB could still use the existing domainA comments by setting the data-href or href property of the comments plugin to the old domainA url.

Comment: Thank you. But, if I take down my domainA url, will the comments still migrate over? Is the href property, just used as a unique ID?

Comment: The href property is essentially acting as a unique id.  Test it.